# C - using a variable in the setup of a for loop

Tags: c, cs50

I was wondering if its posible to do something like this:
if the number is even define a string variable "replace" equal to the name of an array previously defined "arraya", and then use the variable "replace", that contain the string arraya, in the setup of the for loop, and also compare the array with another variable. the code below doesn´t work, but it may help to explain my doubt.

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

int arraya[] = {2,4,6};
int arrayb[] = {1,3,5};

if ( x % 2 == 0)
{
    string replace = "arraya";
}
else
{
    string replace = "arrayb";
}

for (int i = 0, n = sizeof(replace); i < n; i++)  //instead of using arraya or arrayb, use replace dependig on the condition
{
    if ( x == replace[i])  // same here
         {
            break;
         }
         else
         {
            y++;
         }
}
```

PD: I know that in C, there are no strings, just array of characters, but in CS50 they define the type of a variable as string.

Comment: What is `string`?    That is not a standard type in C.

Comment: Looks like a two dimensional array is needed. Then `x % 2` indexes the correct array.

Comment: What you are asking for is something called "reflection"--the ability to examine variable names at runtime. C can't do this. Variable names do not exist in compiled code. You, however, can do it manually if you like by making structures that contain variable names and pointers to the variable, and put them in some searchable structure.

Comment: If you want to get the length of a string, then specific functions are available for that in C's standard library. The `sizeof()` operator will not do what you think it does, not even with CS50's `string` type. Also note that there is a specific SE site for CS50 at https://cs50.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In the CS50 course header, `<cs50.h>`, they define `typedef char *string;`.  I don't think that's a particularly good idea, but that's the way they've done it.  Also note that you define two separate variables `replace`, and they're each limited in scope to the set of braces `{ … }` in which they're defined.  They are not accessible outside the braces.  In context, they probably don't even exist, and the compiler is presumably complaining about `sizeof(replace)`.

Comment: regarding: `for (int i = 0, n = sizeof(replace); i < n; i++) ` the C preprocessor operator returns a `size_t`, not an `int`.  Suggest the variables `i` and `n` be declared as having type `size_t`

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do,

```
int *p;
int len;
if ( x % 2 == 0)
{
    p = arraya;
    len = sizeof(arraya)/sizeof(arraya[0]);
}
else
{
    p = arrayb;
    len = sizeof(arrayb)/sizeof(arrayb[0]);
}
for (int i = 0, n = len; i < n; i++)  
{
    if ( x == p[i])  // same here
    ...
}
```

There is no implcit string type in `C`. And also you can't get the length of an array without using `sizeof` on the array object itself. Also there is no way you will get the array based on the content of the string.

Also you can do it another way also - that is to abstract out the implementation logic which is common for both in a function and then do this:-

```
void fun(int *a, int size){
   ....
}
```

In `main()`

```
if ( x % 2 == 0)
{
    fun(arraya, sizeof(arraya)/sizeof(arraya[0]));
}
else
{
    fun(arrayb, sizeof(arrayb)/sizeof(arrayb[0]));
}
```